# Custom Export All in Ribbon is not working after migration from SharePoint 2010 to 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

Can you please help on the below issue.
[image]

Comment: try to edit this to ListDefaultView

Comment: This issue happened to many lists, I have tried to export default view and remaining all the Views data with custom Export All, getting the error while exporting. Not facing the issue in SharePoint 2010. After migration have the problem.

Comment: I meant you need to edit the custom export solution, to edit URL to correct way...